# Installing Ubuntu GNOME (server) 14.04

Tags: server, active-directory, domain-server, file-server, samba4

I am working in a new company now, and my boss asked me if there is a way of having a server with the same features as Windows without the costs. The server should have Active Directory, DHCP server, and a firewall. In my search I found Ubuntu, and I would like to know if it is possible, and how should I take the first steps.

Comment: You Question is not specific enough. What should the server do? It wouldn`t be without cost, somebody has to do the migration. Also you should use 14.04, 13.04 is out of support.

Comment: The server should have active directory, DHCP server, and Firewall

Comment: What you want is this i think: http://i.justrealized.com/2009/how-to-install-gnome-in-ubuntu-server/. It wasn't hard to find on a search, and it is prefered that you do research before asking here.

Comment: @Tim That link is broken (I get a 404 page).

Comment: Yes, it is now... :/

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, you can...

- use [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto) to act as a file server in a Windows environment integrated into Active Directory.
- set up a [DHCP server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server).
- use [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo), an advanced firewall built into the kernel.

The first step is to [install Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation), then configure the services you need. If you have any trouble along the way, search the questions here on AskUbuntu or ask one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.com/for-smbs/) distribution (Ubuntu based). IMHO you don't need graphical interface (GNOME or whatever). The standart installation comes with web interface for adminstration and Xfce desktop environment, but you may prefer the installation from [packages](https://wiki.zentyal.org/wiki/Installation_Guide#Installing_packages) and select what you need.

- For Active Directory take a look at [Zentyal Directory](http://www.zentyal.com/for-smbs/zentyal-directory/)
- For Network Configuration & Firewall  take a look at [Zentyal Gateway](http://www.zentyal.com/for-smbs/zentyal-gateway-utm/)